# RecyclerView item expanding animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I am writing descendant of DefaultItemAnimator. When the list item is clicked adapter makes visible some of item's child and its size must be grown. 
animateChange is called (with same old and new ViewHolder) and I animate item's bounds. It work but sometimes before animation is started expanded item have time to draw itself once and I can see flickering. Please, get me any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

I've found the cause. I called RecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition right after notifyItemChanged. Without smoothScrollToPosition it is working as expected.